# 1Gbps Full Duplex has 100x slower upload than 100Mbps Full Duplex

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

Notice how on 1Gbps Full Duplex, I only get 0.18 Mbps upload:

[image: 128.3 Mbps down, 0.18Mbps up, 1.0 Gbps Full Duplex]

Yet on the lower 100Mbps Full Duplex, my upload speed is normal:

[image: 50.0 Mbps down, 14.1 Mbps up, 100 Mbps Full Duplex]

"Auto Negotiation" leads to the same issues as 1Gbps Full Duplex.

I've tried three different ethernet cables from the router to my computer and have had the same issue on all three. The one I'm using now has been tested to not have similar issues with other computers. Additionally, there aren't upload speed issues over the Wi-Fi from the router. Large Send Offload v2 is off for both IPv4 and IPv6 (speeds get even slower when they're on).

Is this intended behavior? Or some sort of resolvable issue?

[image: Driver details]

Comment: Connect your PC directly to another PC's gigabit Ethernet port, and run iperf in each direction to test this. That way you're eliminating your modem and router (and any network switch) from being a possible problem.

Comment: @Ramhound the first time I've ever been able to use a wired connection on this computer, and its only been with this specific router. However, this has been happening since I've been using a wired connection; 4-5 weeks ago.

Comment: Its not the way things are supposed to be. Don't underestimate a driver issue or dubious hardware- Realtek Ethernet chips are notoriously bad.

Comment: Alright. So, now the issue is happening even on 100Mbps Full. I've verified that it's not my ethernet cable, I've used multiple cables. I've verified that it's not my whole computer, Wi-fi works properly (albeit with much higher latency). I've verified that it's not my router (other machines get the correct speeds). I've verified that it's not repeated testing, as I continue to get 300Mbps down no matter how many tests I do, and 0.2Mbps up no matter how long I wait between tests. I've run out of driver settings to try and change, nothing seems to work. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem initial (super slow upload), same network card. Took me a while to get to the same point (1Gbps slow upload).
In my case it was a PC connected to the wifi router via LAN. When I connected my macbook via wire and USB-C network interface to the same router, everything worked fine.

As it turned out, the reason was in router's Fragmentation Threshold (complicated setup with router connected via wifi to another router). I set it to 2300 (while default is 2346) and the problem went away.